# Avoiding "Too broad exception clause" warning in PyCharm

Tags: python, exception, pycharm

I'm writing an exception clause at the top level of a script, and I just want it to log whatever errors occur. Annoyingly, PyCharm complains if I just catch `Exception`.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()

try:
    raise RuntimeError('Bad stuff happened.')
except Exception:  # <= causes warning: Too broad exception clause
    logging.error('Failed.', exc_info=True)
```

Is there something wrong with this handler? If not, how can I tell PyCharm to shut up about it?

Comment: If you're looking to turn warnings off they can be found in the settings.  I believe you can search for the exact errors you are looking to change.

Comment: Thanks, @AugustWilliams, but I just want to tell PyCharm that this try/except block is good. I still want it to complain about other blocks, in case they aren't logging or dealing with the exception properly.

Comment: I remember seeing somewhere about ignore this occurrence or something like that. Can't remember where this button was though, apologies.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From a comment by [Joran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40775710/4794#comment68775868_40775710): you can use `# noinspection PyBroadException` to tell PyCharm that you're OK with this exception clause. This is what I was originally looking for, but I missed the option to [suppress the inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/suppressing-inspections.html) in the suggestions menu.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()

# noinspection PyBroadException
try:
    raise RuntimeError('Bad stuff happened.')
except Exception:
    logging.error('Failed.', exc_info=True)
```

If you don't even want to log the exception, and you just want to suppress it without PyCharm complaining, there's a new feature in Python 3.4: [`contextlib.suppress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress).

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.suppress(Exception):
    raise RuntimeError('Bad stuff happened.')
```

That's equivalent to this:

```
try:
    raise RuntimeError('Bad stuff happened.')
except Exception:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about your PyCharm version (mine is 2019.2), but I strongly recommend disabling this PyCharm inspection in File> Settings> Editor> Inspections and type "too broad". In Python tab, deselect "too broad exceptions clauses" to avoid those. I believe this way PyCharm would show you the correct expression inspection

Comment: In PyCharm 2021.2.2 this option doesn't exist. I just realized "# noinspection PyBroadException" only helps if it is inserted right before each try statement

Answer (score 3):

I found a hint in this closed [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-2698) for PyCharm:

> I suggest you to mark this inspection as 'okay' if the except  block makes use of exception instance `e` somehow.

Because I'm logging with `exc_info=True`, I'm implicitly using the current exception object, but PyCharm doesn't know that. To make it explicit, I can pass the exception object to `exc_info`. Since Python 3.5, the [logger methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) have accepted an exception instance to report, as well as accepting any truthy value to report the current exception and stack trace in the log.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()

try:
    raise RuntimeError('Bad stuff happened.')
except Exception as e:
    logging.error('Failed.', exc_info=e)
```

Comment: That's going to be horribly misleading to anyone reading this code later.

Comment: you could also add `# noinspection PyBroadException` to right above the `try:` this would tell pycharm (and probably other IDE's that you know its too broad and you are ok with it)

Comment: Why wouldd this be horribly misleading? Looks like the logging module checks either `isinstance(exc_info, BaseException)` in which case it extracts the data from the exception, `tuple` in which case it assumes the exc_info is accurate, or truthy in which case it uses `sys.exc_info()`. Passing `exc_info=True` and `exc_info=e` should yield identical results, no? (`logging.__init__` at line 1461)

Comment: Thanks, @Sam, I hadn't noticed that change to `exc_info`. I've updated the answer to explain it better.

Answer (score 3):

I am reluctant to turn off warnings as a matter of principle.

In the case presented, you know well what the exception is.  It might be best to just be specific.  For example:

> ```
> try:
>     raise RuntimeError("Oops")
> except RuntimeError as e:
>     print(e, "was handled")
> ```
>
> will yield "Oops was handled".

If there are a couple of possible exceptions, you could use two except clauses. If there could be a multitude of possible exceptions, should one attempt to use a single try-block to handle everything?  It might be better to reconsider the design!

Comment: Then again, there are cases where you do not know the errors in advance and still want to catch them. For example in the [socket library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socket.html#notes-on-socket-timeouts): "In non-blocking mode, operations fail (with an error that is unfortunately system-dependent) if they cannot be completed immediately"