# What is the most pythonic way to handle all possible exceptions in block of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

My question may look very abstract, so I`ll give an example. If I have code like this:

```py
try:
    # some python code where different exceptions can be thrown
except Exception:
    #exceptions handling
```

PyCharm will say that using so broad Exception class is bad, so what should I do if I want to handle all the exceptions possible with the same block of code?

Comment: Pycharm will stop the warning if you use `except Exception as e:` as then use `e` in the block. For example `print(e)`

Comment: So this approach is generally good?

Comment: Handling all exceptions without distinction is bad, that's why PyCharm is warning you. You can still go on and do it, but it's not a good practice. See the following on why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594113/bad-idea-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-python

Comment: Its not generally good practice, but in some specific cases its necessary. For example running a script in a server that shouldn't stop, in that case you would log the exception instead of exitting the program.

Comment: Okay, but what should I do if my script should not stop anyway, but I don`t need the instance of Exception in except block?

Comment: You might still prefer that certain types of exception are _not_ to be caught by the catch-all, e.g. `try: some stuff` `except KeyboardInterrupt: raise` `except Exception as e: print(e)` or whatever. You might also want to log a full traceback for the exception, such as you would normally see if the exception was not trapped (the `traceback` package can help with this). To answer the last question, you could just decide not to use the exception info, but it might give you some debugging headaches later.

Comment: In general  you should know what exceptions could logically be thrown and catch those, any other exceptions would indicate a bug. If you must catch all exceptions, not atleast logging them, you would have no idea what could have went wrong, so its not a good idea.

Comment: So there is two acceptable ways to deal with this problem: either use one catch block and use an instance of Exception or use multiple specific blocks. Am I right?

Comment: The less info that you log from your catch-all `except`, the more that you will later wish you had logged, when you are trying to work out what went wrong. So if you are going to catch "everything", then log plenty. But in _most_ circumstances, if you get exceptions that "should" not arise, then the correct thing to do is to let them abort the program in the normal way, and then you fix the bug rather than hiding it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775709/avoiding-too-broad-exception-clause-warning-in-pycharm for how to tell PyCharm not to warn about it.

Comment: If you know which exceptions can be thrown you can do something like that : ```except (ExType1, ..., ExTypeN) as e: do_something()``` to execute the same block for all exceptions of type ExType1, ..., or ExTypeN.